# can't prevent view from showing in Tab bar Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` here with five (5) tab bar items, 1 of them must not show it's view when a `TabBarItem` is clicked. I know I had to use this code on my `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(           UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSInteger tabIndex = [[tbController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

if(tabIndex == 1)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

But I don't know why it didn't work for me. I want to ask if all I have to do is just add this code on the `AppDelegate.m` and that's all? Am I missing some step? I'm new in iOS. Please help, I am using story board.

Answer (score 0):

You should set tab bar controller's delegate. Like `_tabBarController.delegate = self`.

Comment: I added this `@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarCont;` on my `TabBarController.h` and on `TabBarController.m` I added `@synthesize tabBarCont = _tabBarCont` and on `viewDidLoad` i added `_tabBarCont.delegate.self`. But unfortunately nothing happpened.

Comment: Because you have the code above in your app delegate, you should do something like `_tabBarCont.delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`.